Pyrogram: Showing OTP expired even when entered in time
This is the code:
class TelegramWorker(QThread):
    otp_sent = pyqtSignal(object)
    auth_complete = pyqtSignal(bool, str)

    def __init__(self, action, phone_number=None, otp=None, phone_code_hash=None, password=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.action = action
        self.phone_number = phone_number
        self.otp = otp
        self.phone_code_hash = phone_code_hash
        self.password = password
        self.client = None

    def run(self):
        asyncio.run(self.perform_action())

    async def perform_action(self):
        try:
            self.client = Client(TELEGRAM_SESSION, api_id=API_ID, api_hash=API_HASH)
            await self.client.connect()

            if self.action == "send_code":
                sent_code_info = await self.client.send_code(self.phone_number)
                self.otp_sent.emit(sent_code_info)
            elif self.action == "auth_with_otp":
                try:
                    await self.client.sign_in(
                        self.phone_number, self.phone_code_hash, self.otp
                    )
                    self.auth_complete.emit(True, "Authentication successful!")
                except errors.PhoneCodeInvalid:
                    self.auth_complete.emit(False, "Invalid confirmation code. Please try again.")
                except errors.PhoneCodeExpired:
                    self.auth_complete.emit(False, "The confirmation code has expired. Request a new one.")
            elif self.action == "auth_with_password":
                await self.client.check_password(self.password)
                self.auth_complete.emit(True, "Authentication successful!")
            await self.client.disconnect()
        except errors.SessionPasswordNeeded:
            self.auth_complete.emit(False, "Password is required for authentication.")
        except Exception as e:
            self.auth_complete.emit(False, str(e))

class TelegramAuthenticationDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Telegram Authentication")
        self.setFixedSize(400, 300)
        self.phone_number = None
        self.sent_code = None
        self.worker = None
        self.resend_timer = QTimer(self)  # Add a QTimer for resending OTP
        self.resend_timer.timeout.connect(self.update_resend_timer)
        self.resend_countdown = 60

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        --- relevant UI code---

    def authenticate(self):
        otp = self.otp_input.text().strip()
        if not otp:
            QMessageBox.information(self, "Error", "Enter the OTP.")
            return

        self.worker = TelegramWorker(action="auth_with_otp", phone_number=self.phone_number, otp=otp, phone_code_hash=self.sent_code.phone_code_hash)
        self.worker.auth_complete.connect(self.handle_auth_result)
        self.worker.start()

    def handle_auth_result(self, success, message):
        if success:
            QMessageBox.information(self, "Success", message)
            self.accept()
        else:
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error", message)
            if "password" in message.lower():
                self.password_input.setVisible(True)
                self.otp_input.setVisible(False)
                self.action_button.setText("Authenticate with Password")
                self.action_button.clicked.disconnect()
                self.action_button.clicked.connect(self.authenticate_with_password)
            elif "expired" in message.lower() or "invalid" in message.lower():
                self.otp_input.clear()
                self.action_button.setText("Send OTP on Telegram")
                self.action_button.clicked.disconnect()
                self.action_button.clicked.connect(self.send_otp)
                self.otp_input.setVisible(False)
                self.resend_label.setVisible(False)

    def authenticate_with_password(self):
        password = self.password_input.text().strip()
        if not password:
            QMessageBox.information(self, "Error", "Enter your Telegram password.")
            return

        self.worker = TelegramWorker(action="auth_with_password", password=password)
        self.worker.auth_complete.connect(self.handle_auth_result)
        self.worker.start()

    def start_resend_timer(self):
        self.resend_countdown = 180
        self.resend_label.setText(f"Didn't receive OTP? Resend in {self.resend_countdown} seconds")
        self.resend_timer.start(1000)

    def update_resend_timer(self):
        self.resend_countdown -= 1
        if self.resend_countdown <= 0:
            self.resend_timer.stop()
            self.resend_label.setText("Didn't receive OTP? Resend")
            self.action_button.setText("Resend OTP")
            self.action_button.clicked.disconnect()
            self.action_button.clicked.connect(self.resend_otp)
        else:
            self.resend_label.setText(f"Didn't receive OTP? Resend in {self.resend_countdown} seconds")

    def resend_otp(self):
        self.resend_label.setVisible(False)
        self.otp_input.clear()
        self.otp_input.setVisible(False)
        self.send_otp()

Now even after entering the OTP immediately (within a few seconds), it is showing an error - "The confirmation code has expired. Request a new one.". I think this is due to a bug or issue with the pyrogram library. I have tried all different approaches to confirm the OTP but have not been successful with anyone.
Please help to fix this issue. Thanks in Advance.

I can help you to check with below solutions

you can modify a bit the method perform_action to avoid unnecessary disconnections and let client remain connected while processing the OTP



async def perform_action(self):
   ....
        elif self.action == "auth_with_otp":
            try:
                # Ensure the client remains connected during OTP verification
                await self.client.sign_in(
                    self.phone_number, self.phone_code_hash, self.otp
                )
                self.auth_complete.emit(True, "Authentication successful!")
            .....
        # add this
            except Exception as e: 
                self.auth_complete.emit(False, str(e))
        ......




handle_auth_result method, ensure that the UI will allow to resend OTP in case of expire



def handle_auth_result(self, success, message):
   .....
    # Trigger resend logic
            self.start_resend_timer()




Kindly check the start_resend_timer and update_resend_timer methods whether it is resetting appropriately and prevents frequent expiry of OTP



self.resend_countdown = 180 # check the suitable value here




try to debug the Log information in the perform_action method to check the delay or miscommunication with the Telegram API.


It is still not working.
